# Python: Interrupting the execution of a function

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm new to Python and trying to build a tic-tac-toe game. I guess there are a ton of solutions on the internet, but I wanted to try it without looking at them. Now halfway through I ran into a problem: The function `def player_input(board)` works as intended when I input a position that's not already taken. However, when there is already a marker "X" or "O" there, I want `if board[marker_pos] == "X" or board[marker_pos] == "O":` to catch this and start the function again, so the user sees the input field again.

It does that, but as you can see below in the two pictures, when I try to put the mark in an already occupied field, the function seems to execute completely. I thought it would get interrupted when I call the function from within itself `(player_input(board)`). So it shows me the result of `display_board(board)` and `print "iTurn is %s " %iTurn` twice or however many tries it took me to put the mark in an empty position.

[image: 1st input]  [image: 2nd and 3rd input]

```
from IPython.display import clear_output

    def intro():
        board = [0]*9
        print "Player1, your marker is 'X'."
        print "Player2, your marker is 'O'."
        global iTurn
        iTurn = 1 

    def display_board(board):
        print "    |   |"
        print "  " + str(board[6]) + " | "  + str(board[7]) + " | "  + str(board[8]) 
        print "-------------"
        print "  " + str(board[3]) + " | "  + str(board[4]) + " | "  + str(board[5]) 
        print "-------------"
        print "  " + str(board[0]) + " | "  + str(board[1]) + " | "  + str(board[2]) 
        print "    |   |"


    def player_input(board):
        global iTurn
        if iTurn%2 != 0:
            marker_pos = input("Player1, please write which position (1 through 9) your marker should go")
        else:
            marker_pos = input("Player2, please write which position (1 through 9) your marker should go")     
        marker_pos -= 1

        if marker_pos < 0 or marker_pos > 8:
            print "Position needs to be between 1 and 9."
            player_input(board)

        else:
            if  board[marker_pos] == "X" or board[marker_pos] == "O":
                print "Position is already occupied."
                player_input(board)
            elif iTurn%2 != 0:
                board[marker_pos] = "X"
            else:
                board[marker_pos] = "O"    
        iTurn += 1
        print "iTurn is %s " %iTurn
        #check_winning(board)
        display_board(board)
```

**edit:** This would be the code for the while loop

```
while (marker_pos < 0 or marker_pos > 8) or (board[marker_pos] == "X" or board[marker_pos] == "O"):
    if (marker_pos < 0 or marker_pos > 8):
        print "Position needs to be between 1 and 9."
    elif (board[marker_pos] == "X" or board[marker_pos] == "O"):
        print "Position is already occupied."
    marker_pos = input("Please write where your marker should go (1 through 9).")
    marker_pos -= 1
```

Comment: in `player_input` you should use loop instead of running function again.

Comment: @furas How would I do this? I have two conditions that both have to be checked  (´marker_pos´ being between 1 and 9 and ´board[marker_pos]´ being empty) each time the user inputs something. Do I pack them both into one while loop and then have an if-statement inside the loop to check which one of the two has been violated (because it would result in a different message to the user).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `while True` to repeat it and `break` to exit loop

```
def player_input(board):
    global iTurn

    while True:
        if iTurn%2 != 0:
            marker_pos = input("Player1, please write which position (1 through 9) your marker should go")
        else:
            marker_pos = input("Player2, please write which position (1 through 9) your marker should go")     
        marker_pos -= 1

        if marker_pos < 0 or marker_pos > 8:
            print "Position needs to be between 1 and 9."
        else:
            if  board[marker_pos] == "X" or board[marker_pos] == "O":
                print "Position is already occupied."
            elif iTurn%2 != 0:
                board[marker_pos] = "X"
                break
            else:
                board[marker_pos] = "O"
                break

    iTurn += 1
    print "iTurn is %s " %iTurn
    display_board(board)
```

---

You can write it little simpler

```
def player_input(board):
    global iTurn

    if iTurn%2 != 0:
        text = "Player1, please write which position (1 through 9) your marker should go"
        mark = "X"
    else:
        text = "Player2, please write which position (1 through 9) your marker should go"        
        mark = "O"

    while True:
        marker_pos = input(text)
        marker_pos -= 1

        if marker_pos < 0 or marker_pos > 8:
            print "Position needs to be between 1 and 9."
        else:
            if board[marker_pos] != 0:
                print "Position is already occupied."
            else:
                board[marker_pos] = mark
                break

    iTurn += 1
    print "iTurn is %s " % iTurn
    display_board(board)
```

Comment: I knew there had to be a way to write it simpler. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is, that you don't exit the function which got an invalid position. That's why - after the `player_input` with the valid position is run - the one called before also runs the last commands.
This can be fixed if you simply return after calling player_input again.

Change the `player_input(board)`s to

```
return player_input(board)
```

or

```
player_input(board)
return
```

Comment: Thank you. What's more pythonic? This solution or, as suggested above, using a while loop? See also my edit in the post what the while loop would look like.

Comment: I'd also use a loop. It uses less resources, because the functions can than stop after recieving an incorrect input. Without using loops all functions stop only after a correct input is processed.